# How To Access Native Android Date Picker And Time Picker From Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, datepicker, datetimepicker, android-timepicker

I have been trying to find a way for ages to access Android's Native Date Picker and Time Picker in Unity via script. Most of the method's need a plugin or add-ons that cost money. I am looking for a way to do this without pluug-ins but would not be against the idea of using one.

Comment: What is your unity version?

Comment: I currently am using Version 2018.2.7f1 (Personal Edition)

Answer (score 2):

You may try with this package which i have not used. But hope it would work. Please try with demo included on that package.

[Android Native Dialogs and Functions Plugin](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/android-native-dialogs-and-functions-plugin-106497)

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible using `AndroidJavaObject` and `AndroidJavaClass`, but i assume you have already tried that route.

I just crossed this bridge myself, i needed background audio and the only way to make that happen was with a native Foreground Service and using Native Media API's.
I have successfully wrapped up with that side of the project now and moved over to accomplishing the same functionality with apple (much harder so far..)

I highly recommend that you just bite the bullet and write your own plugin man, as i had to. it was well worth it. its also completely free. the time invested is really worth the functionality it opens up for your current and future projects

This was by far the best YouTube tutorial to get your started (just install Android Studio First) -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmNMugkOQBI

Followed by : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNKSXzWOnlI

Once you have your **plugin created**, it should just be a matter of adding one java method that 'Sends' a string back to a given C# method

it took me a solid week to figure it all out. but if you have any questions i can answer them in the comments :) just ask